# how change RecyclerView's item's background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How should I change Recycler View's items's background from activity, I mean if I want to set first item red color, second green and third blue and so on...

Comment: [so] isn't a coding service; you have to show what you have tried and explain what you need it to do that you can't get it to do...

Comment: in this case I'm asking cause I don't know how to do

Comment: And that in itself is fine; but the community here expects that you will have at least tried to do what you need to before asking for help.  You will find a better level of support given if you show what you have tried and explain how it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating the view holder that time you can change its background color and return it in onCreateViewHolder

Comment: and what if I want to change color after creating? I have to recreate?

Comment: Then you can do it when you are binding the view